# Angularjs: set parent directive scope value with child directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I'm not sure this is the way to do this, but my goal is the following:

- I have a parent directive
- Inside the parent directive's block, I have a child directive that will get some input from the user
- The child directive will set a value in the parent directive's scope
- I can take it from there

Of course the problem is that the parent and child directives are siblings. So I don't know how to do this. Note - I do not want to set data in the

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rrosen326/CZWS4/

html:

```
<div ng-controller="parentController">
    <parent-dir dir-data="display this data">
        <child-dir></child-dir>
    </parent-dir>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
var testapp = angular.module('testapp', []);

testapp.controller('parentController', ['$scope', '$window', function ($scope, $window) {
    console.log('parentController scope id = ', $scope.$id);
    $scope.ctrl_data = "irrelevant ctrl data";
}]);

testapp.directive('parentDir', function factory() {
    return {
        restrict: 'ECA',
        scope: {
            ctrl_data: '@'
        },
        template: '<div><b>parentDir scope.dirData:</b> {{dirData}} <div class="offset1" ng-transclude></div> </div>',
        replace: false,
        transclude: true,
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.dirData = attrs.dirData;
            console.log("parent_dir scope: ", scope.$id);
        }
    };
});

testapp.directive('childDir', function factory() {
    return {
        restrict: 'ECA',
        template: '<h4>Begin child directive</h4><input type="text"  ng-model="dirData" /></br><div><b>childDir scope.dirData:</b> {{dirData}}</div>',
        replace: false,
        transclude: false,
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            console.log("child_dir scope: ", scope.$id);
            scope.dirData = "No, THIS data!"; // default text
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: The video from Brian and the plunker from Jesus were perfect. I edited my fiddle with one addition - using a $watch to continuously update the parent directive's scope (otherwise it only happens once in Jesus' plunker). http://jsfiddle.net/rrosen326/7Dq4e/

Answer (score 27, accepted):

If you want that kind of communication, you need to use `require` in the child directive. That will require the parent `controller` so you need a `controller` there with the functionality you want the children directives to use.

For example:

```
app.directive('parent', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    transclude: true,
    template: '<div>{{message}}<span ng-transclude></span></div>',
    controller: function($scope) {
      $scope.message = "Original parent message"

      this.setMessage = function(message) {
        $scope.message = message;
      }
    }
  }
});
```

The controller has a message in the `$scope` and you have a method to change it.

Why one in `$scope` and one using `this`? You can't access the `$scope` in the child directive, so you need to use `this` in the function so your child directive will be able to call it.

```
app.directive('child', function($timeout) {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    require: '^parent',
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs, parentCtrl) {
      $timeout(function() {
        parentCtrl.setMessage('I am the child!')
      }, 3000)
    }
  }
})
```

As you see, the link receives a fourth param with the parentCtrl (or if there is more than one, an array). Here we just wait 3 seconds until we call that method we defined in the parent controller to change its message.

See it live here: http://plnkr.co/edit/72PjQSOlckGyUQnH7zOA?p=preview

Answer (score 6):

First, watch [this video](http://egghead.io/video/2CdivtU5ytY).  It explains it all.

Basically, you need to `require: '^parentDir'` and then it will get passed into your link function:

```
link: function (scope, element, attrs, ParentCtrl) {
    ParentCtrl.$scope.something = '';
}
```