# Two way data binding failing with ng-model

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

My two-way data binding using `ng-model` is not working.

- [AngularJS Docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive)
- [Relevant Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18501127/angularjs-set-parent-directive-scope-value-with-child-directive?rq=1)

Parent directive template:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Company Phone</label>
    <input ng-model="formData.company_phone" type="phonenumber" class="form-control" placeholder="Company Phone">
</div>
```

And the child directive:

```
.directive('input', [function(){
    return: {
        restrict: 'E',
        require: '?ngModel',//right now this is binding to this directive scope, not a parent one
        link: function($scope, element, attr, ngModel){
            if (attr.type !== 'phonenumber') {
                return;
            }
        //some code to validate a phone number
        $scope.$apply(function () {
            //bind updated number, but I need this to reflect in the parent scope
            $scope[attr.ngModel] =  formattedNumber; 
}
```

Comment: some relevant code would help

Comment: @charlietfl I added some code, my apologies.

Comment: If you're using ng-model, and binding to the same model, then they are already two-way binding to their respective views. It should be working OOTB. If it is not working, try to find out if the ng-models are referencing the same instance. There are several postings about why ng-model should have a '.' in it it - it may be relevant here.

Comment: @pixelbits I was using ng-model and the object notation for the model and I actually just figured out what I was doing wrong. I'll post an answer with an explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used `$parse` to solve this issue:

```
.directive('input', ['$parse', function($parse){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        require: '?ngModel',
        link: function(scope, element, attr, ngModel){
            var getter = $parse(attr.ngModel);
            var setter = getter.assign;

            if (attr.type !== 'phonenumber') {
                return;
            }
            //code that validated a phone number

            scope.$apply(function () {
                setter(scope, formattedNumber);
            });
         }
    }
}]);
```