# AngularJS : Autocomplete directive is not working inside ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

Autocomplete is working fine in single text field like in text field with id="1" and i'm getting data inside "scope.SelectedICD9Code" but when i try same thing in ng-repeat, its logging the data but not accessable to other function..

```
 var app = angular.module("PEMR", []);

    app.directive('icd9AutoComplete', function ($timeout) {
        return function (scope, Element, Attrs) {
            Element.autocomplete({
                source: function (request, response) {
                    PageMethods.SearchICD9ByDescription(request.term, function (data) {
                        response(data);
                    });
                },
                minLength: 2,
                select: function (event, ui) {
                    scope.SelectedICD9Code = ui.item;
                    console.log(scope.SelectedICD9Code);
                    $timeout(function () {
                        Element.trigger('input');
                    }, 0);
                }
            });
        };
    });
```

My HTML

```
<input id="1" icd9-auto-complete ui-items="names">

<div ng-repeat="Suppose 1 to 5" >
 <input id="2" icd9-auto-complete ui-items="names">
</div>
```

HERE HOW I'm ACCESSING THE SELECTED DATA

```
$scope.SomeFunction= function () {
 console.log($scope.SelectedICD9Code);
}
```

Comment: Do you change the `id` of `<input>` inside of the `ng-repeat`? Otherwise you will have 5 elements with the same id, which is not valid.

Comment: yes i changed , but i think that does not matters.

Answer (score 0):

The problem appears to be an issue with your scope. The `ng-repeat` creates new child scope for each element so the scope for the first input (id 1) is the parent scope and the `ng-repeat` creates 5 new child scopes of this parent scope. The child scopes have no problem getting the `names` etc from the parent scope (polymorphic inheritance nature of javascript), but the child scopes assign a the value of `ui.item` to the `$scope.SelectedICD9Code` of the *child* scope not the parent scope.

See http://jimhoskins.com/2012/12/14/nested-scopes-in-angularjs.html for a longer explanation and see this other question [Angularjs: set parent directive scope value with child directive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18501127/angularjs-set-parent-directive-scope-value-with-child-directive) for more detail on how to get the child scope to change the parent.