# How can parent scope access child scope in Angular JS using ES6?

Tags: angularjs, ecmascript-6

I have a nested directive. I need to access the value selected in child directive from parent directive.

Comment: I think you will end up having to go the other direction - from the child to the parent. Check out [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18509399/548997) for more details of how to accomplish this.

Comment: I am using ES6 for JS. Can you please help me in that way?

Comment: Try implementing the general idea in that answer and then update your question with samples of your code and what you are having problems with and someone will likely be able to help. You are unlikely to find anyone willing to write your code for you, though.

Comment: Yes, I know that. Actually my code is bit messy as of now. Will try and let you know. But is this the only way to do it? Can't I access child scope instead of modifying parent scope in child?

Comment: don't create an isolated scope for child. then they will share the scope. have a look at this: http://www.undefinednull.com/2014/02/11/mastering-the-scope-of-a-directive-in-angularjs/

Comment: _"I need to access the value selected in child directive from parent directive"_ That's what two-way-binding is for, isn't it?